# unit testing src/groovy class files

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I'm working on unit tests for a grails application. I've been successful at testing services and domains but stuck trying to test classes in the `src/groovy` folder. What do I have to do to access the `saveCreateAndCall` method?

```
@Artefact("Controller")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class BaseController<T> extends RestfulController<T> {

    protected def saveCreateAndCall(Object instance, boolean flush = false, Closure c) {
        if (instance.save(flush: flush)) {
            c.call instance
        } else {
            errorCreateResponse(instance)
        }
    }
```

any advice or feedback would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your `BaseController` as an abstract class and let it in the controllers folder.

```
abstract class BaseController<T> {
}
```

Normally I tend to create an concrete controller to test my base abstraction and use the `@TestFor` to use the Grails testing features for controllers.

Or you can annotate your test:

```
@GrailsUnitTestMixin
@Mock(MyDomainClass) 
class BaseControllerTest extends Specification {
}
```